# Telegram REST API - phone.requestCall

Tags: php, rest, telegram, telegram-bot

Maybe a trivial question, but I am trying to understand how I can transform this documentation: https://core.telegram.org/method/phone.requestCall into a REST call.

I know you can send message with:

```
$query = http_build_query([
    'chat_id' => $channelId,
    'text' => $text,
]);
https://api.telegram.org/bot{$botApiToken}/sendMessage?{$query}";`
```

but I tried with

```
$query = http_build_query([
    'user_id' => $userId,
]);
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$botApiToken}/phone.requestCall?{$query}";
```

and got a 404. I also tried without `phone.`.

My need is to call a Telegram group from a PHP code.

Comment: Do you mandatory need to use of Telegram Bot for this? Because it seems not possible to make phone calls with the Bot API endpoint, ie. https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}

Comment: @v-g no it is not mandatory. I just want to make a group "ring". If you have other idea, I'll take it.

Comment: In reality, it's not event mandatory. For the context, my project is to create an emergency button through LoRa without having to pay anything in monthly fee. I created a webhook to call a PHP page on a website I have, and I want to notify people in case of use of the emergency button. I am able to send a message telling "the button has been pressed". However, if everyone sleeps, by example, we won't see the message. Therefore, my need to call the group to wake up someone.

Comment: *In reality, it's not event mandatory to use Telegram